# ERROR: modpost: "root_mem_cgroup" [fs/xxx/xxx.ko] undefined

Tags: linux, build, module, compilation, undefined-symbol

I built a kernel module, I got the following errors:

```
ERROR: modpost: "root_mem_cgroup" [fs/xxx/xxx.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "__detach_mounts" [fs/xxx/xxx.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "mem_cgroup_update_lru_size" [fs/xxx/xxx.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "__mod_lruvec_state" [fs/xxx/xxx.ko] undefined!
```

The module xxx.ko does not use those symbols.
Why did it happen? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the cause: xxx.ko references some functions and those functions reference the `undefined` functions. But the `undefined` functions are not exported by the kernel.